# 95% confidence intervals of sensitivity and specificity exceeding 100%. How is it possible?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, sensitivity-specificity

I read this abstract (unfortunately, I have no access to the full text): https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.318.7177.193b.

**How is it possible for 95% confidence intervals of sensitivity and specificity to exceed 100%? Does it depend by the computing method? Eventually, may a specific computing method be used?**

(I use R)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple. It *isn't* possible. The authors of this comment critique a different paper in which an approximation was used that did not make sense. Here is the key sentence from the comment you link:

> Such impossible results arise when
>    the standard large sample method for
>    calculating confidence intervals for proportions is used when the proportion is near to
>    zero or one or when the sample is small, or
>    both.

Such impossible results indicate that the standard approximation is not adequate in this case.

Note that one of the authors of the comment, [Douglas Altman](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=douglas+altman), is an extremely prolific and competent medical statistician.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. Could you please explain what do you mean by "standard approximation"? Is it a computing method? Are there any other methods?

Comment: The article that Deeks & Altman critique is [Stell & Gransden (1998, *BMJ*)](http://www.jstor.org.ezproxy.lancs.ac.uk/stable/25179577). Unfortunately, they don't describe which of [various approximations for CIs for proportions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) they use, and I wasn't able to recreate their calculations in what little time I have today. With the small numbers involved ($n=36$, 17 true positives), one might be able to calculate a CI for an observed sensitivity of 100% by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your further clarification and the link you provided, I will study them